# Combine results of two table in SQL

Tags: sql

i have two tables one contain computer_science_book and Mechanical_engineering_book i want the result which contail all books of computer_science_book and Mechanical_engineering_book .
give me suggetions.

Comment: First suggestion:  review how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.  Second   suggestion:  edit your question with sample data, desired results, and any query you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all for that:

```
select * from computer_science_book 
union all
select * from Mechanical_engineering_book
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNION` operator:

`select columns from computer_science_books 
UNION
select columns from mechanical_eng_books`

Note that the structure of the results from computer_science_books needs to match the structure of results from mechanical_eng_books. The reason is that, as asked for, there is only one result table. There is also the `UNION ALL` operator. The difference is that `UNION` removes duplicates whereas `UNION ALL` returns all combined rows.